# How to make <div> work both inside offcanvas and outside of offcanvas?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `<div class="test">test</div>` work in two positions at once, one position should be displayed just on the page, and the other position should already be offcanvas
i am using bootstrap 5 offcanvas

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 5</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasTop" aria-controls="offcanvasTop">Toggle top offcanvas</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-top" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasTop" aria-labelledby="offcanvasTopLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasTopLabel">Offcanvas top</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

as I didn’t play with positioning, it didn’t work out for me, maybe someone came across?